# How to use JQuery event delegation on element attribute change?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, event-delegation

I have a form with a button to edit an existing record. On button click, a modal opens to update the record, including a button to delete an existing file attached to the record which, when clicked triggers an ajax call to a delete_file PHP script. If a file exists, its file name is previewed in the 'p' element.

The problem I'm running into is that if the user edit's a record that didn't contain a file, uploads a file, and then deletes it without saving the record, my existing code doesn't work to delete the file. It's because HTML is dynamically being generated on file upload to place the file url in a button attribute which is not available to pass to file delete.

After researching I believe the solution is event delegation. I've tried several recommendations but none have worked. How can I:

1. add a file (with filename in "$("button").attr("data-fileurl") // this works
2. after clicking 'delete file' button, store $("button").attr("data-fileurl") in a variable
3. pass the url variable to the delete_file function

HTML:

```
<div id='file_upload' class='file-upload'>
  <input type='file' id='file_input' style='opacity:0;' />
  <p class='file_upload_text'>Click to upload file</p>
</div>
<div id='file_upload_preview' class='file-upload file-preview' style='display:none;'>
  <div class='file_preview'></div>
  <button id='fileurl' data-fileurl='' class='file_delete'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var filesToUpload = [];
  var fileUrlDelegated = ""; 
  $('#file_input').on('change', function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files[0];
    filesToUpload.push(files);
    prepareUpload(filesToUpload);  
  $(".file_delete").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document.body).on('change', "button [data-fileurl]", function (event) { // not working
      fileUrlDelegated = $(event.target).attr("data-fileurl");
    });
    delete_file(fileUrlDelegated);
  });
});
      
function prepareUpload(file) { // upload file; dynamic HTML generated after an ajax call; this works
  var parent = $("#file_input").parent();
  var previewID = parent.attr("id") + "_preview";
  var previewParent = $("#"+previewID);
  previewParent.show();
  previewParent.children(".file_preview").empty().append( preview );
  previewParent.children( "button" ).attr("data-fileurl", data.url );
  parent.children("input").val("");
  parent.hide();
}
    
function delete_file (file_url) {  // works as long as url is provided
  $(".file_preview").text("");
  $("button").attr("data-fileurl", "");
  $("#file_upload_preview").hide();
  $("#file_upload").show();
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("fileurl", file_url);
  $.ajax({
    url: general_globals.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to rewrite your logic and rest of `code` look fine to whats its doing. To `delete` file and pass the `data-fileurl` - You can simply check if the file URL exist at all or not which was generated by prepare Upload.

Also, to get the data attributes we can simply use [.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method and write `.data('fileurl')` in `jQuery` to get the button `fileurl` and then pass that to our delete `function` for the `ajax` to be call for `backend`.

To get the **correct** `fileURL` we can use `$(this)` in our delete function which refer to the element we have clicked on which will be `.file_delete`

We will use `event Delegation` in your case just to be safe since HTML are dynamically created.

**Replace your delete file function to this:** (Code tested on localhost and working)

```
//Delete file
$(document).on('click', '.file_delete', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Get the file URL
  var fileURL = $(this).data('fileurl')
  //Check if file URL exist - then call delete else do not anything
  if (fileURL != '') {
    //Call delete function
    delete_file(fileURL);
  } else {
    return false
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi there, @AlwaysHelping! Thanks for your answer. I'll work on it and report back.

Comment: it worked! Thanks, AGAIN, for your expertise. I accepted your answer as it solved the original problem. However, a different problem arose. If a file existed, then was deleted, then another file attached, fileURL retained the url of the 1st deleted file, not the 2nd file to be deleted. This is an edge case that I won't spend time solving, but just out of curiosity, isn't this what event delegation is supposed to handle?

Comment: Also, I confirmed that the correct url is in "data-fileurl" in the HTML.

Comment: @GSimmons you are welcome happy to help. For the second scenario you have - the way I would handle that is that I will clear delete buttons dataURL in my delete function. Also I would recommend using class of the button to assign - add new and remove old file URL using .Attr - :)

Comment: if I understand you correctly, I believe that I am already doing that. In the delete function I use $("button").attr("data-fileurl", "") and it works. In the upload function I use previewParent.children( "button" ).attr("data-fileurl", data.url ). Both of these work as expected. So, when the 2nd file is requested to be deleted, "data-fileurl" in the HTML is different than the console logged fileURL from $(this), which is the 1st deleted file.

Comment: @GSimmons Sorry for getting this reply late. Are you sure that on delete success of 1st file the fileURL is empty - and new uploaded file url is placed onto the button in prepare upload ? Can you console.log each part and see what happens let me know.

Comment: @GSimmons I try to reproduce this issue you said above. All seems to be working fine. Also can you make add this => in your button `$(".file_delete").attr("data-fileurl", "");` just in case

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Here are confirmed test results: 0) start of test - data-fileurl contains url of file A; 1) delete file A - fileURL contains url of file A, data-fileurl successfully emptied, file successfully deleted from server; 2) upload file B - data-fileurl contains url of file B, file successfully uploaded to server; 3)  delete file B - fileURL contains url of file A, data-fileurl still has url of file B because delete function fails as 'file doesn't exist'.

Comment: @GSimmons I still do not understand how this can happens. the file b url having file a url on delete. It baffles me. I can not even point own what could be done here until i see everything in the background on how the data is fetched and populated :(

Comment: yeah, it baffles me too. I really appreciate you hanging in there with me. But, you solved the original problem, for which I am very grateful!

Comment: I got it to work by using your suggestion to use $(".file_delete).attr("data-fileurl"). I was adding data-fileurl on "button" and after submitting the form the attribute was dynamically added to that button, not the delete button. Changed this and now it works as expected. You continue to be my HERO! Thank you very much.

Comment: @GSimmons Very glad to hear that. Yes i had a big doubt on this `$("button").attr("data-fileurl")` thats why i want to use the class method because instead of a button since it was applying data on every button on that page. Happg Coding :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FileReader API instead of relying on AJAX calls. You can make a method like

```
function readURL() {
  var input = grab your input here;
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
};
```

This way, you don't touch your database until the user saves the record, so your problem is solved.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I just read up on FileReader. I don't think this is the right solution to my problem. My code uploads files as expected and stores the custom url in "button data-fileurl"; e.g., button data-fileurl="https://www.example.com/x/filename.png". My problem is that I need this exact url to pass to the delete_file function. But, the url doesn't exist at document ready because the file is uploaded thereafter, I can't figure out how to grab data-fileurl which was dynamically generated after the page loaded.

Comment: Ok, after re-reading your answer, I see where you'e going with this. I don't want to have to re-write a bunch of already working code, but maybe I can re-arrange the code to upload the file only after the record is saved.